# Can I make general formula for this problem

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to find how many pairs of numbers satisfy this condition on $[1,n]$.

For given $n$ , how many pairs $(a,b)$ are there such that $gcd(a,b) = 2^t , t > 0 $ for some whole number $t$.

All pairs $(a,b)$ should be bounded by $1\leq a < b \leq n $ .

Now I know that if $2|a \land2|b \implies 2|gcd(a,b)$ and this excludes all odd numbers .

But the space is too big to count for very large $n$.

Can I make general formula for $\forall n $ ?

$a,b,n,t$ are whole numbers.

Comment: Is an asymptotic answer sufficient? It's not too hard to figure out that, if $f(n)$ is the number of such pairs, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ is positive and finite (and it's not even so hard to compute this constant). I don't see how one would get an exact answer for all $n$ though without considerable computation.

Comment: that is the main problem here, for $n = 10^{6} $ , with brute force it takes about 3-4 hours to compute them , if its not possible for a general formula to be made maybe decreasing the search space will help but this of course requires more properties for such pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi(n)=\#\{(x,y) : 1 \leqslant x,y \leqslant n, \gcd(x, y) = 1\}$. Then, for $1 \leqslant d \leqslant n$,
$$\#\{(x,y) : 1 \leqslant x,y \leqslant n, \gcd(x, y) = d\} = \psi\big(\lfloor n/d \rfloor\big),$$
and the union of these sets is just $\{(x,y) : 1 \leqslant x,y \leqslant n\}$. This gives
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{d=1}^{n}\psi\big(\lfloor n/d \rfloor\big)=n^2} \implies \psi(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{n}\mu(d)\lfloor n/d \rfloor^2$$
(by the "second" [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations)). This leads to a solution of your problem:
$$2^t \leqslant n \implies \#\{(a, b) : 1 \leqslant a < b \leqslant n, \gcd(a, b) = 2^t \} = \frac{\psi(\lfloor 2^{-t} n \rfloor) - 1}{2}.$$

There's an algorithm which computes $\psi(n)$ in $\mathcal{O}(n^{1+\epsilon})$ time and $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ space (without computing any values of $\mu$). The idea is to use the "blue" formula above recursively (or rather iteratively), noting that there are just $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ different values of $\lfloor n/d \rfloor$ for $1 \leqslant d \leqslant n$, which allows to simplify the sum; namely, for any $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$,
$$n^2=\sum_{d=1}^{n}\psi\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor\right)=\sum_{d=1}^{\lfloor n/(k+1) \rfloor}\psi\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor\right)+\sum_{d=1}^{k}\psi(d)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d+1}\right\rfloor\right),$$
and we may put $k=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ here. This recurrence for $\psi(n)$ gives the algorithm.

Comment: I was just going to ask how do you compute $ \psi (n) $ , it will help lots if you can or provide some info

Comment: How does one compute $\mu (d)$

Comment: The formula for $\psi$ with $\mu$ is still of use (to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi(n)}{n^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ - see comments to the OP).

Comment: Does $$\psi (n) = n \prod_{p|n}(1+\frac{1}{p})$$ here  ?

Comment: No, there's no such simple formula here.

Comment: for $ n = 10^{2} $ the number is $1031$ and for $ n = 10^{6} $  it is $ 321418433   mod1000000007 $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87740/discussion-between-metamorphy-and-noodle).