# How many numbers with no common divisor are there?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inclusion-exclusion, arithmetic-functions

There is quite general question.

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ be a set.

> Calculate the following:
>   $$W_{k}=\sum_{\substack{a_{1},...,a_{k}\in A\\ a_{i}\neq a_{j} \text{ if }i\neq j\\ \gcd(a_{1},...a_{k})=1}}\hspace{-1.5em}1$$

For example $W_{2}=\sum_{2\le a \le N}\phi(a)$

Where $\phi$ is Euler totient function.

But I have no idea how to carry it on.

I wonder whether inclusion-exclusion principle should be used.

I hope for help.

Regards.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Even the $\sum \phi(n)$ [doesn't have a closed form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html) so far as I can tell.

Comment: @saul, but it does have good asymptotics.

Answer (score 1):

We have $W_k=W_k(n):=\#A(n,k,1)$, where
$$A(n,k,d)=\left\{(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\in\{1,\ldots,n\}^k\ \middle|\ \begin{gathered}i\neq j\implies a_i\neq a_j\\ \gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=d\end{gathered}\right\}.$$
Now clearly $\#A(n,k,d)=W_k(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)$, and $\bigcup_{d=1}^{n}A(n,k,d)$ is the set of *all* $k$-tuples of distinct numbers from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. This set has $(n)_k=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ elements, which gives
$$\sum_{d=1}^{n}W_k(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)=(n)_k\implies W_k(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{n}\mu(d)\big(\lfloor n/d\rfloor\big)_k$$
by [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) (for computing, it may be preferable to use the first of these equalities, as a recurrence relation for $O(\sqrt{n})$ needed values of $W_k$, rather than the last formula; see the bottom of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059011/can-i-make-general-formula-for-this-problem/3059033#3059033) for details).